# Website loading deleted file

Tags: web, http-caching

Working on this website I was going to add a simple .hide(); and onclick animate(); functions to a menu, but the menu div wasn't closed (stupid mistake). When I upload the file to the live website it hides everything in the website cause of the open div tag, obviously I fix it and also delete the jQuery function but when I upload the file to the FTP the website is still showing the old file for some reason.

More info: I already deleted the cache/cookies/history off this computer and reloaded the page and re uploaded the file. Also tried in 4 different computers with 3 different IPs I did a search of all the files and the code is not there anymore. Deleted the directory and it still shows up.

Comment: Do you have the proper permissions on the server?

Comment: Yep. I've been working on this website for the pass 3-4 days.

Comment: Does the website have a server side cache

Comment: Have you looked at the Network tab in developer tools to see if it is downloading the file or pulling it from cache?

Comment: @Anigel Not sure, is there a way i can check that?

Comment: You may also have firewall cache, like if your site is using CloudFlare or something

Comment: what/where is the website hosted on/at ? is it your server or a webhost or a cloud hosting service ? any info on the server would help here

Comment: @CatalinDeaconescu Its a webhost (justhost) and I don't use cloudflare

Answer (score 1):

As i can suggest from your question, i can say its a stupid mistake. Happened to me a few times.

I would try the following:

> 1. Make a working folder of your "new" website - locally
> 2. Delete EVERY file and folder from your server (of course only your whole website)
> 3. Get sure that nothing is displayed when you open it at the browser, should be fail
> 4. Now load your local folder completely to the new, empty space at your FTP

Comment: Yea I was going to do that if all else failed but it seems I will have to.

Comment: It's not a big deal. But really, get sure that your local folder is working. I can guess that you upload the wrong file or sth like that. Sounds like you just bought webspace from a provider, and nothing so complicated happens there, to be sure.

Comment: Its a PHP platform and the file where the html is set up is not even on the ftp server, I deleted the whole directory and it still shows up.

Comment: What do you mean with PHP platform? Be more specific!

Comment: its a groupon clone, it uses MVC for the files so the HTML itself is on a static page calling a $content variable which changes depending on which page the user is. I added some jQuery to that page to change a menu div and since the div wasn't closed it messed up my website, so I deleted the code, closed teh div, re-uploaded and nothing changed, searched through the 3695 files for the code to see if another file had it and it came up "Searching 3695 files for "$("#mainmenu").hide();"

0 matches across 0 files
"

Comment: Test: Download a specific file, change something (add comments), upload it again (overwriting) and see if the change is there. If yes, then maybe your files are changing but your code is still messing up.

Comment: Well, I deleted the whole theme and it still shows up the empty page with a bg image. 

Edit: I'm just going to re-install it, I won't lose anything important since the site is still on the developing part.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than re uploading the file. Delete it, visit it in your browser and verify you get a 404 and then upload it again.

I have had this problem before when re-uploading a file in some FTP clients.